# The bisector of an angle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I have a problem with a bisector. You can see my picture below I've made so far:

[image: problem]

You can see the coding as well:

```
\tikz[thick,main node/.style=draw=black,thick]{
\coordinate(A)at(0,0);
\coordinate(B)at(5,0);
\coordinate(C)at(-2,5);
\coordinate(D)at(7.5,0);

\draw(A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;




\tkzMarkAngle[fill=red!50!white,opacity=.4,size=.64](B,A,C)
\tkzMarkAngle[fill=red!50!white,opacity=.4,size=.64](C,B,A)
\tkzMarkAngle[fill=red!50!white,opacity=.4,size=.64](A,C,B)

\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.35](B,A,C){$\alpha$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.4](C,B,A){$\beta$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.5](A,C,B){$\gamma$}

\tkzLabelSegment[below=1pt](A,B){$c$}
%\tkzLabelSegment[right=1pt](B,C){$a$}
\tkzLabelSegment[left=1pt](A,C){$b$}


\tkzDrawPoint[fill=blue](A)
\tkzDrawPoint[fill=blue](B)
\tkzDrawPoint[fill=blue](C)

\tkzLabelPoint[below=1pt](A){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below=1pt](B){$B$}
\tkzLabelPoint[above=1pt](C){$C$}


\path[name path=alfa2](A)--(55.9:7);
\path[name path=seg](B)--(C);

\draw[name intersections={of=alfa2 and seg, by=F}][dashed, orange] (A)--(F);

\tkzDrawPoint[fill=blue](F)
\tkzLabelPoint[above=2pt](F){$F$}
\tkzLabelSegment(F,B){${a\over 2}$}
\tkzLabelSegment(C,F){${a\over 2}$}

\draw[dashed](B)--(17.77:1cm);
}
```

The problem is in the last line. Beta is 35.54° (previously I made the same triangle in GeoGebra and it said, that beta is 35.54°). Since I need the half of this angle I wrote  `(17.77:1cm)`  and if I know well it means, that 1 cm in direction 17.77°, and 17.77° is equal to 35.54/2 as we know. But as you can see the dashed line is not bisector of beta. I've also tried to write 162.23° instead of 17.77° but again LaTeX hasn't drew the dashed line through beta/2.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: I think the angle you want is `180-17.77`, _not_ `17.77`.  BTW, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This is especially important for `tikz` as there are numerous libraries.

Comment: Sorry about that, I keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angle you want is `180-17.77`. Furthermore, you want to use `++` so that you get the position relative to the current point:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\MyAngle}{180-17.77}
\draw[dashed](B)-- ++(\MyAngle:2cm);
```

the diagram you get is

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In `tkz-euclide`, which is the package you're already using, you can automatically draw a bisector without calculating the angle yourself. It's pretty handy. Just write

```
\tkzDefLine[bisector](A,B,F)\tkzGetPoint{a}
\tkzDrawSegment[green, dashed](B,a)
```

Please ignore the wrong coloring of the angles, it's unrelated to the code. Just some nuisance I've been having.

### Output

[image: example image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,5/0/B,-2/5/C,7.5/0/D}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)

\tkzMarkAngle[fill=red!50!white,opacity=.4,size=.64](B,A,C)
\tkzMarkAngle[fill=red!50!white,opacity=.4,size=.64](C,B,A)
\tkzMarkAngle[fill=red!50!white,opacity=.4,size=.64](A,C,B)

\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.35](B,A,C){$\alpha$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.4](C,B,A){$\beta$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.5](A,C,B){$\gamma$}

\tkzLabelSegment[below=1pt](A,B){$c$}
%\tkzLabelSegment[right=1pt](B,C){$a$}
\tkzLabelSegment[left=1pt](A,C){$b$}

\tkzDrawPoints[fill=blue](A,B,C)

\tkzLabelPoint[below=1pt](A){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below=1pt](B){$B$}
\tkzLabelPoint[above=1pt](C){$C$}


\path[name path=alfa2](A)--(55.9:7);
\path[name path=seg](B)--(C);

\draw[name intersections={of=alfa2 and seg, by=F}][dashed, orange] (A)--(F);

\tkzDrawPoint[fill=blue](F)
\tkzLabelPoint[above=2pt](F){$F$}
\tkzLabelSegment(F,B){${a\over 2}$}
\tkzLabelSegment(C,F){${a\over 2}$}

%\draw[dashed](B)--(17.77:1cm);

\tkzDefLine[bisector](A,B,F)\tkzGetPoint{a}
\tkzDrawSegment[green, dashed](B,a)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Much better solution than mine, but since there is no English version of the documentation I have not used `tkz-euclide`.

Comment: @PeterGrill Ah sure, no problem! :D I gave the solution with `tkz-euclide` because the OP was already using the package (all the `\tkz` commands). Your command is interesting as well, I've been struggling with `\pgfmathsetmacro` quite a lot recently.

Comment: `\pgfmathsetmaro` is pretty useful. Just have to watch for the fact that the answer is a real number, so if you want an integer you need to use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`. If your problem is more complicated, please post a question...

Comment: @PeterGrill My problem was more with the `rand` command. If you check my answer to the Advent Calendar challenge, it's by the end of the code. I kind of solved it, but yeah, really energy draining.

Comment: Using `\pgfmathsetmacro\xpos{5*rand}` should work.

Comment: @PeterGrill  here http://www.highschoolmathandchess.com/latex/altermundus-packages/ you can find some pieces of the documentation in english.

Comment: @AlainMatthes: Thanks that is helpful. Wondering if it make sense to set up a site where people can contribute to hiring someone to translate the docs to English. There might be enough people just on on TeX.SE.